# C# .xsl view from xml -- only outputs the first element

Tags: xslt, c#-3.0

I'm learning on the fly, and I have commented C# code with /// that generates xml after:

```
csc Class1.cs /out:Class1Docs /rescurse:*.cs /doc:Class1Doc.xml
```

My xsl file (the relevant part) is like so:

```
<xsl:for-each select="doc">
            <br>
              <xsl:value-of select="members/member"/>
            </br>
            <br>
              <xsl:value-of select="summary"/>
            </br>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
```

The problem is that I need to output the member, summary, params, and return value.
I only get the 'member/member' returned:
Class1 Class

How do i select the xsl:value of for each tag ?

Comment: Provide a **complete minimal example** of your XSLT and source XML. Most likely you are missing proper XML namespace declarations in the XSLT.

Comment: I'm using: xmlns:xsl=""http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">. Should I be using one of the pop ups that Visual Studio 2008 gives me?

Comment: Oh, and it only generated this in the .xml file:  <?xml version="1.0"?>

Comment: Without input sample and desired output, this is not a real question.

Comment: I don't know why it was upvoted, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My xsl file (the relevant part) is
>   like so:
>
> ```
> <xsl:for-each select="doc">
>  <br>               
>   <xsl:value-of select="members/member"/
>  </br>             
>  <br>               
>   <xsl:value-of select="summary"/>             
>  </br>           
> </xsl:for-each>       
> </body>     
> </html> 
> </xsl:template>
> ```

**This is badly malformed XML**!

Let's think that the relevant, well-formed portion is:

```
  <xsl:for-each select="doc">
    <br>
     <xsl:value-of select="members/member"/>
    </br>
    <br>
      <xsl:value-of select="summary"/>
    </br>
  </xsl:for-each>
```

**There are many problems with this code**:

1. AFAIK **the (x)HTML element `br` should have no content**. Maybe you wanted:
2. `<xsl:value-of select="members/member"/>`

**The `<xsl:value-of>` instruction creates a text node that contains the string value of the first node only**, that is specified in the XPath expression in the `select` attribute.

Probably you wanted:

`<xsl:copy-of select="members/member/text()"/>`

.3. **Specifying all literal result elements and using `<xsl:for-each>` within a single template is not a good XSLT programming practice**. It is recommended to use more templates and correspondingly, `<xsl:apply-templates>` instead of `<xsl:for-each>`.

Comment: I was just using the <br> because I can generate the text, but it is all one big run-on sentence.

Comment: I can't really post the whole XML example because it's internal info, and they would consider it sensitive information do to the type of contract.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't really post the whole XML example because it's internal info

Then it's easy enough to provide an example that exhibits all the necessary properties of the real data, surely? You can't expect people to help you with one hand tied behind their backs.

Like other responders, I'm guessing, but my guess is that you failed to realise that in XSLT 1.0, the xsl:value-of instruction only outputs the string value of the first node in the sequence. If for some reason you can't move to XSLT 2.0, you need to put the xsl:value-of inside an xsl:for-each or xsl:apply-templates loop.

Comment: I can, and don't call me Shirley.